# How to create a dictionary that allows multiple keys in a user input and print out key values combined in one string?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, key

I stuck with a python dictionary and will appreciate your help, since I did not find any examples of the similar issue on the internet.

I am trying to create a program that will allow

1. enter multiple keys in a user input field
2. and then print out all values for the keys entered in one string.

For example, if a user inputs "country1, country2, country3", the program prints out "'location1', 'location2', 'location3'.

In the code below, it allows only one country and prints out only one location. I tried different approaches with lists, dictionaries, tuples - could not figure it out.

```
country_dict = {
'country1': 'location1',
'country2': 'location2',
'country3': 'location3',
}

country = input("Enter country: ")
if country.lower() == 'country1':
    country_dict['country1']
if country.lower() == 'country2':
    country_dict['country2']
if country.lower() == 'country3':
    country_dict['country3']

print (country_dict[country])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your input and then look for locations:

```
country_dict = {
'country1': 'location1',
'country2': 'location2',
'country3': 'location3',
}

country = input("Enter country: ")
countries = country.split()
locations = ''
for key in country_dict.keys():
    if key in countries:
        locations += f'{country_dict[key]} '

print(locations)
```

Example:
Input: `country1 country2`
Outputs: `location1 location2`

Comment: Thank you for your help, David! Working and elegant solution too!

Answer (score 0):

```
#declare country_dict
country_dict = {
'country1': 'location1',
'country2': 'location2',
'country3': 'location3',
}
#take input country(s)
country = input("Enter country: ")
out=[]
for i in country.split(","): #Change split string based on your requirement
    out.append(country_dict[i])

print (",".join(out)) #change join string based on your requirement
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below commented code:

```
countries = input("Enter country: ").split(',') # split the input based on ,
result = []
for c in countries: # iterate over the input countries
    result.append(country_dict.get(c.strip().lower(), '')) # get value from the dict, empty string if key is not found

print(', '.join(result)) # join the result using ', '
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much, Krishna!